# How can i programatically get the next time a specific set alarm is set to go off?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i'm currently setting the alarm via the following..

```
//set the alarm
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent);
```

i don't seem to see an `AlarmManager` method that allows me to `get` the time of that set alarm... Is there a way to do it from somewhere else in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alarms can be read, but it is undocumented. On most android devices it will be in the content provider:

```
content://com.android.alarmclock/alarm
content://com.android.deskclock/alarm
```

Although many OEMs create there own alarm providers, e.g:

```
content://com.htc.android.alarmclock/alarm
```

on HTC phones.

Comment: i use content://com.android.deskclock/alarm to get cursor , but it has security problem , how should i do that @@? could u give me a sample?

Comment: Using undocumented apis seems pretty dangerous, they could change between releases. Google strongly discourages this.